# How to make docker wait for SQL script inside /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d to be executed

Tags: database, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, database-migration

I am dockerizing an application with two services in docker-compose.yml: a web image build from php:7.3.28-apache and a database image build from postgres:11.12-alpine. Inside database Dockerfile I am executing a sql file to populate the database by doing:

`COPY ./dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`

In my web image I do a migration. But the migration should only occur after the database end executing the sql file. So I use the wait-for-it.sh script to wait for the database port to be available:

```
CMD composer install ; wait-for-it -t 0 db:5432 -- bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate ; apache2-foreground
```

The problem is that the port db:5432 becomes available before dump.sql file end execution.

I already tried

```
depends_on:
    - db
```

in docker-compose.yml and the problem persists.
Is there a way to lock the port db:5432 until dump is done, or a way to make web service to wait for the end of dump execution in db service?

Comment: The sql file is executing nicely in database, so the populating step is ok. My problem is that I would like to make the migration only after "retoring" the dump file. Since the migration command called in the web service, I would like to make the web service somehow wait for db service. I was thinking in using sleep in web service, but it does not seems a neat solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to utilise `HEALTHCHECK [OPTIONS] CMD command`

The command after the CMD keyword can be either a shell command (e.g. `HEALTHCHECK CMD /bin/check-running`) or an exec array (as with other Dockerfile commands; see e.g. ENTRYPOINT for details).

The command’s exit status indicates the health status of the container. The possible values are:

0: success - the container is healthy and ready for use

1: unhealthy - the container is not working correctly

2: reserved - do not use this exit code

Probably you can create some shell script

```
#!/bin/sh

# if your last table exists we assume may be 
# we are now ready for migration 
# put whatever logic you have to ensure data import was successful

# if file exits then exit code 0 else exit code 1
[ -f  "/path/to/my/last/table" ] && exit 0 || exit 1
```

In docker-compose.yml you need

```
depends_on:
      database:
           condition: service_healthy
```